# Based on this job description, does the employer expect full code to be submitted with an application?

Tags: software-industry, applications

A job listing I'm looking at says:

> Assuming `<environment>`, describe start-to-end how you would setup a system monitor ... including in your overview any scripts that you would write ...

Would this mean I should be submitting pseudo-code or the actual full code of said script?

Or would it be appropriate to contact them and ask, even if I have no direct contact person?

Recruiters are not involved here, by the way.

Answer (score 9):

IMO it means describe how you would do carry out  the task in **overview**. So no - not real code just an overview of what you need to do, what kinds of scripts you'd need and why you'd need them and what kind of things they would do. I'd also add whether I'd write them, or how get them other places and why.

It sounds partly like a free consultancy fishing exercise, and partly a more efficient way of narrowing down CVs. And also a way of determining your communications skills.

I would use it as way of ensuring that the things I think are important in the task are conveyed to the recruiter without too much detail but enough to show that you know what you are talking about.